# Programmatically determine common parts of the DOM from a web spider result

Tags: algorithm, dom, web-scraping, web-crawler

Quite often I need to extract data from a web interface that lacks a nice, well organized API. As a toy-example, consider [J! Archive](http://j-archive.com/), a collection of Jeopardy Questions.

A proper game id look like this:

http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=2485

whereas an incomplete game looks like:

http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=1032

If I wanted to extract the questions, I would look over the DOM and find the labeled elements of interest, like:

```
<td class="clue">
    ...
    <td class="clue_value">$200</td>
    <td class="clue_order_number"><a href="suggestcorrection.php?clue_id=131201" title="Suggest a correction for this clue" rel="nofollow">22</a></td>
```

The vast majority of the games are "proper games", in that the returned page has as identical DOM structure. 
In this *particular case*, it is clear that the I can search for some specific classes, but *a priori* I wouldn't know where to look.
Is there a way to programmatically determine this DOM structure that is mostly common to a large subset so I can easily find the the real data in the underlying html?

Comment: I've read your last para several times, and am not sure what you're asking. Do you want an algorithm to take an HTML page and give you a CSS/XPath expression to find data? Do you mean for this site in particular, or in general?

Comment: @halfer I want an algorithm to take a _collection_ of HTML pages and find the common elements of the tree. Essentially I'd like to create an automagic-API for websites that lack one.

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense, thanks. No ideas here, unfortunately.